# c# winforms - calling form from another dll (c#) missing show() and showdialog()

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dll

I have some project (app) in c# winforms(.net framework 3.5). Project is builded from few smaller projects. In all this smaller project there are some forms. Right now I need create seperate project (app) and I want use one of this smaller project by his dll.

I adding dll to project by reference, I see form that I need so I create object. I see some my custom proporties but I don's see basic methods like Show() or ShowDialog(). Honestly I don't know were is problem. I tired some someone else's dll from different source and different framework's and It's worked. So I'know there is problem in my 'main' app but I don't remember any proporties which disable visibiltes of this methods. What can I do to get all the methods back?

Project which I try using dll are library type. When I'm using it in that main app I see all methods.

Maybe I show screen:
[image: class screen that try call form form another dll]

Comment: what do you mean by "I don't see" the methods? have you tried calling the methods on the object?  If your custom object inherits from `System.Windows.Forms.Form` it should have `Show` and `ShowDialog` available.

Comment: Yes I'm trying call methods of object Form. And I see only my proporties.

Comment: could you show us the definition for your class and how you are trying to call the methods that are inherited from `Form`

Comment: I post screen, hope that will be more legible.

Comment: Your TestXmlForm is declared as `object` or derives from `object` (directly or by inference) -- Post its definition and show how you're importing that class